# need to convert MMDDYYYY string to date using momentjs

Tags: javascript, typescript, momentjs

I am trying to convert string "12012019" to date format using momentjs instead of doing any string manipulation. 
Does anyone have any idea or suggestion?

Comment: Can you post some code?

Comment: Answer mentioned below is correct but in code issue was somewhere else due to which mine functionality was not working. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read the [doc](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/)

```js
moment('12012019', 'MMDDYYYY') // Moment instance, you can call .toDate() if you want to convert to native Date
```